# Pydbg setting registers without breakpoint?

Tags: python, thread, register

In pydbg, is it possible to set a register without having it hit a break point first? Consider the following example break point handler:

```
def handler_breakpoint(mdbg):
  print "[+]Hit breakpoint"
  mdbg.set_register("EIP", 0)
  return DBG_CONTINUE
```

This code works, but if I call `mdbg.set_register("EIP", 0)` (Note, outside the handler it would be `dbg.set_register("EIP", 0)`) from outside a break point handler it returns `pdx: [6] GetThreadContext(): The handle is invalid`. How could I write this?

Comment: What do you call "outside a breakpoint"? Either your program is not running and you cannot modify anything, or you program is launched and you have to stop at a breakpoint before being able to modify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the registers without an event is fundamentally not possible rethink and reformulate your query

if you do not want to do it in break-point handler  of any debugger you must suspend the process , Get the Thread's context and Set the thread's context and Resume the process

pydbg can do all this iirc in the script body out of break-point handler

**EDIT Added a Sample Script**

```
from pydbg import *
from pydbg.defines import *
def handler_breakpoint (pydbg):
    if pydbg.first_breakpoint:
        return DBG_CONTINUE
def handler_access_violation (pydbg):
    if pydbg.dbg.u.Exception.dwFirstChance:
        print "crashed and land here on FirstChance"
    else:
        print "crashed and land here on SecondChancee"
    return DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

dbg = pydbg()
dbg.set_callback(EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT, handler_breakpoint)
dbg.set_callback(EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, handler_access_violation)
dbg.load("c:\windows\system32\calc.exe")
print "pid of calc.exe is = %d" % dbg.pid
dbg.suspend_all_threads()
for thread_id in dbg.enumerate_threads():
    thread_handle  = dbg.open_thread(thread_id)
    thread_context = dbg.get_thread_context(thread_handle)
    print "eax = 0x%08x" % thread_context.Eax
    thread_context.Eax=0xdeadbeef
    dbg.set_thread_context(thread_context,0,thread_id)
    thread_context = dbg.get_thread_context(thread_handle)
    print "new eax = 0x%08x" % thread_context.Eax
    print "yay we are going to crash now accessing random crap in eax"  
dbg.resume_all_threads()
pydbg.debug_event_loop(dbg)
```

**executed**

```
:\>python changereg.py
pid of calc.exe is = 1940
eax = 0x00b52d6c
new eax = 0xdeadbeef
yay we are going to crash now accessing random crap in eax
crashed and land here on FirstChance
crashed and land here on SecondChancee
```